# Stop C program on matching user input

Tags: c, fgets

I am trying to break out of a loop when the user inputs the word "exit". If the user inputs anything aside from the word exit, I would like the program to skip a line and write a single "$". It works but is acting a little funny. Here's the code and the output:

```
int main()
{
    char input[5];
    int x = 5;
    while(x){
        printf("\n$");
        fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
        x = strcmp(input, "exit");
    }
}
```

Heres the output (on my input of: "a" return "asdfasdfasdf" return "exit" return):

```
$a

$asdfasdfasdf

$
$
$
$exit

Process returned 0 (0X0) execution time : 110.855s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

So my question is: Why are there so many extra "$"s? How do I only get one "$" per return?

Comment: Unrelated nitpicks: Rather than giving `x` a meaningless value before the `while` loop, use a `do-while` loop.  And you're missing a `return 0;` at the very end of `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're only reading 4 characters per loop.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. But if I read any more characters then my strcmp wont work because "exit" is only 4 characters. Ideas?

Comment: No, your strcmp "wont work" because the line is actually `"exit\n"`, not `"exit"`.

Comment: I think you have `strcmp` mixed up with `strncmp`

Comment: Thank you melpomene. Solved.